# <strong> tag getting replaced to <b> tag in CQ5

Tags: html, tags, aem

I'm using [Rich Text Editor](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/configuring_rich_text_editor.html) with [MiscTools](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.rte.plugins.MiscToolsPlugin) plugin to edit text in my website but when I open the HTML editor and create sth like this

```
<p><strong>Strong text</strong></p>
```

the CQ immediatelly rewrites it to

```
<p><b>Strong text</b></p>
```

Is it possible to disable this behaviour? I need to use the `<strong>` tag because of my CSS styles.

I'm using copy of text component from `/libs/foundation/components/text`.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can’t you just add the `b` selector into the rules you have for `strong`?

Comment: I would recommend using a more up to date editor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't very much documentation around this, but the default htmlRules configuration is eating your tags as part of its DOM processing/clean-up.

In particular, the defaults for the [HtmlRules.DocType](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.rte.HtmlRules.DocType) `semanticMarkupMap` (part of the `typeConfig` configuration property) will change `<em>` tags to `<i>` tags and `<strong>` tags to `<b>` tags.

I don't know if you can disable this directly, but you can update the map with an identity mapping (i.e. map `b` tags to `b` tags) so that nothing gets changed.

Add an `htmlRules` node like the following to your dialog.xml (as a sibling of the `rtePlugins` node):

```xml
...
<rtePlugins jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
  ...
  <misctools
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    features="sourceedit"/>
</rtePlugins>
<htmlRules jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
  <docType jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <typeConfig jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
      <semanticMarkupMap jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        b="b" 
        i="i"/>
    </typeConfig>
  </docType>
</htmlRules>
...
...
```

or you can add nodes directly to your dialog in CRXDE Lite if you're not using maven or something similar (this screenshot shows the default, unmodified `<i>` to `<em>` mapping -- don't forget to change that if that's not what you want):

[image: CRXDE Lite node view]

Comment: This solution works perfectly! Thank you for new informations :)

Answer (score 1):

in semanticMarkupMap, add property "strong" with value "b" to automatically replace  tags with  in your rte text (and "em" property with value "i" for italic)