# How to insert <strong>-Tags instead of <b>-Tags on RichText widget

Tags: extjs, aem, extjs3

On a dialog I have RichText widget configured only with the bold plugin.

My Problem now is, that I have to change it so that the content is not saved inside `<b>`-Tags but inside `<strong>`-tags.

I tried to solve this with overriding the `CQ.form.rte.commands.DefaultFormatting.getTagNameForCommand` function. The Result is looking like this:

```
getTagNameForCommand: function(cmd) {
    var cmdLC = cmd.toLowerCase();
    var tagName = null;
    switch (cmdLC) {
        case "bold":
            tagName = "strong";
            break;
        case "italic":
            tagName = "i";
            break;
        case "underline":
            tagName = "u";
            break;
        case "subscript":
            tagName = "sub";
            break;
        case "superscript":
            tagName = "sup";
            break;
    }
    return tagName;
}
```

Unfortunately it works only if I open the dialog and set something "bold". After saving and reopening the dialog again it is not possible anymore to remove the `<strong>`-Tags.

I also tried to override/extend the `CQ.form.rte.plugins.FormatPlugin` and `CQ.form.rte.commands.DefaultFormatting` to support a "strong" command. This results also in the same problem.

My client wants the `<strong>`-tag because of some SEO issues. He won't accept the `<b>`-Tag.

Is there a way to solve that?

Greetings
Sören

EDIT
The solution given on [<strong> tag getting replaced to <b> tag in CQ5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946117/strong-tag-getting-replaced-to-b-tag-in-cq5) doesn't work. Adding the described configuration does not save strong tags. As I understand the solution it is only for the MiscTools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [<strong> tag getting replaced to <b> tag in CQ5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946117/strong-tag-getting-replaced-to-b-tag-in-cq5)

Answer (score 2):

In AEM 6.3 I've been able to get the RTE to use **strong** and **em** tags in place of **b** and **i** by adding the following node as a sibling to the **uiSettings** and **rtePlugins** nodes in the dialog.

```
<htmlRules jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <docType jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <typeConfig jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                useSemanticMarkup="{Boolean}true">
            <semanticMarkupMap
                    b="strong"
                    i="em"/>
        </typeConfig>
    </docType>
</htmlRules>
```

I've also noticed that you have to add a space to previously authored richtext content in order to get the component to notice the change and swap the tags.

Comment: This was the best solution I found for this. It worked in our 6.5 instance as well.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing in AEM6.  I've taken the approach of copying the relevant js, `/libs/cq/ui/rte/core/commands/DefaultFormatting.js` and adding it under the apps content folder, `/apps/cq/ui/rte/core/commands/DefaultFormatting.js` I then amended the copy of DefaultFormatting.js copied under apps.  AEM6 then seems to use the 'overlay' technique to apply the strong tag.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946117/strong-tag-getting-replaced-to-b-tag-in-cq5)

and

then on `typeConfig` node add the `boolean property useSemanticMarkup` as true.